# hadoop map reduce -archives not unpacking archives

Tags: hadoop, archive

hope you can help me. I've got a head-scratching problem with hadoop map-reduce. I've been using the "-files" option successfully on a map-reduce, with hadoop version 1.0.3. However, when I use the "-archives" option, it copies the files, but does not uncompress them. What am I missing? The documentation says "[Archives (zip, tar and tgz/tar.gz files) are un-archived at the slave nodes"](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html), but that's not what I'm seeing.

I have created 3 files - a text file "alice.txt", a zip file "bob.zip" (containing b1.txt and bdir/b2.txt), and a tar file "claire.tar" (containing c1.txt and cdir/c2.txt). I then invoke the hadoop job via

```
hadoop jar myJar myClass -files ./etc/alice.txt -archives ./etc/bob.zip,./etc/claire.tar <input_path> <output_path>
```

The files are indeed there and well-formed:

```
% ls -l etc/alice.txt etc/bob.zip etc/claire.tar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop     6 Aug 20 18:44 etc/alice.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop   282 Aug 20 18:44 etc/bob.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop 10240 Aug 20 18:44 etc/claire.tar
% tar tf etc/claire.tar
c1.txt
cdir/c2.txt
```

I then have my mapper test for the existence of the files in question, like so, where 'lineNumber' is the key passed into the mapper:

```
String key = Long.toString(lineNumber.get());
String [] files = {
    "alice.txt",
    "bob.zip",
    "claire.tar",
    "bdir",
    "cdir",
    "b1.txt",
    "b2.txt",
    "bdir/b2.txt",
    "c1.txt",
    "c2.txt",
    "cdir/c2.txt"
};
String fName = files[ (int) (lineNumber.get() % files.length)];
String val = codeFile(fName);
output.collect(new Text(key), new Text(val));
```

The support routine 'codeFile' is:

```
private String codeFile(String fName) {
    Vector<String> clauses = new Vector<String>();
    clauses.add(fName);
    File f = new File(fName);

    if (!f.exists()) {
        clauses.add("nonexistent");
    } else {
        if (f.canRead()) clauses.add("readable");
        if (f.canWrite()) clauses.add("writable");
        if (f.canExecute()) clauses.add("executable");
        if (f.isDirectory()) clauses.add("dir");
        if (f.isFile()) clauses.add("file");
    }
    return Joiner.on(',').join(clauses);
}
```

Using the Guava 'Joiner' class.
The output values from the mapper look like this:

```
alice.txt,readable,writable,executable,file
bob.zip,readable,writable,executable,dir
claire.tar,readable,writable,executable,dir
bdir,nonexistent
b1.txt,nonexistent
b2.txt,nonexistent
bdir/b2.txt,nonexistent
cdir,nonexistent
c1.txt,nonexistent
c2.txt,nonexistent
cdir/c2.txt,nonexistent
```

So you see the problem - the archive files are there, but they are not unpacked. What am I missing? I have also tried using DistributedCache.addCacheArchive() instead of using -archives, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

the distributed cache doesn't unpack the archives files to the local working directory of your task - there's a location on each task tracker for job as a whole, and it's unpacked there.

You'll need to check the DistributedCache to find this location and look for the files there. The Javadocs for [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) show an example mapper pulling this information.

You can use symbolic linking when defining the -files and -archives generic options and a symlink will be created in the local working directory of the map / reduce tasks making this easier:

```
hadoop jar myJar myClass -files ./etc/alice.txt#file1.txt \
    -archives ./etc/bob.zip#bob,./etc/claire.tar#claire
```

And then you can use the fragment names in your mapper when trying to open files in the archive:

```
new File("bob").isDirectory() == true
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response! I have bad news and good news to share. The bad news - what you suggest has no effect - neither "bob" nor "claire" shows up in the local file system.  The good news - when I looked more closely at the local file system, it _does_ unpack bob.zip and claire.tar - into DIRECTORIES named "bob.zip" and "claire.tar". In fact, the DIRECTORY "bob.zip" contains the FILE "bob.zip", as well as "b1.txt" and "bdir/b2.txt" - similarly, the DIRECTORY "claire.tar" contains the FILE "claire.tar", as well as "c1.txt" and cdir/c2.txt. confusing but true.

Comment: If I had looked more closely at the example in http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html, it does show this: "File f = new File("./map.zip/some/file/in/zip.txt");" - note that "map.zip", the zip file, is unpacked into a directory named map.zip.