# How Add Archive or Project Python to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, transform, archive, hiveql

how I can add archive to hive for exemple:

> hive> ADD ARCHIVE path_project/my_project.tar.gz;

and execute this query:

> select transform(field_1,field_2) USING 'python path_project/script.py' from my_yable limit 1;

i tried but not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i want to duplicate this to [hadoop map reduce -archives not unpacking archives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343371/hadoop-map-reduce-archives-not-unpacking-archives), but it does not allow me to because of the answer there is not accepted.

```
ADD ARCHIVE path_project/my_project.tar.gz;
```

when you add an archive `path_project/my_project.tar.gz`, the archive will be extracted to `my_project.tar.gz/`, so you need to reference the script as

```
SELECT transform(field_1,field_2)
USING 'python my_project.tar.gz/script.py'
FROM my_yable
LIMIT 1;
```

and if you look at the example in the document [Class DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) it implies the convention. btw: the supported archive formats are

> Archives (zip, tar and tgz/tar.gz files) are un-archived at the worker nodes